# Calculate an average rating score based on final number rating and number of people who rated

Tags: average, calculator

I would like to calculate an average rating score based on knowing example the final score is 9.2/10 and rated by 286 people ( example: https://foursquare.com/v/coffee-project/56054685498e21a5e4c9d5b2 ). In the example I know 286 people voted and what the final rating is, but what I want to figure out is what was the average rating of given to achieve 9.2/10?

Comment: If the final rating is 9.2, doesn't this imply that 9.2 is the average as well?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but some how seems too simple :/

Answer (score 0):

In most rating systems, the final score is the average of all the ratings, so in your example, I would assume that the average rating is $9.2/10$.

It is possible that a rating system uses a different [measure of central tendency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_tendency). If you can identify the measure of central tendency that is being used and you have enough information, it may be possible to calculate or estimate the average rating.

Sometimes, we use even more complicated rating systems, like the [Elo rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) that predicts the outcome of chess matches, but I doubt foursquare is using anything like that.